# Look for/matching error between a srt/txt file's contents and a Scrollable Textbox (Tkinter)

Tags: python, search, tkinter, find

Still new to coding, so feel free to shake your heads in disbelief. I'm attempting to create a program which has 3 panes:

1. Middle Pane - scrollable Textbox which shows the contents of a 10,000-50,000+ word txt/rtf file and allows it to be edited *(haven't researched how to implement saving yet)*.
2. Left Pane - a headings view (like the Navigation pane in Word), intended to display the same txt/rtf file but only lines beginning with '#' for example *(I know it's a mess at the moment, each line beginning with # in the txt/rtf file is being thrown together as one string showing \s instead of spaces, but I'm not looking into that yet one challenge at a time)*.
3. Right Pane - intended to show the contents of a second, separate txt/rtf file which is a short list of 50 items (all beginning on new lines, so 50 lines) - all sentences. However I need the ability for any line/list item's text color to change if it matches text in the Middle Pane's scrollable Textbox.

So for example, if the user ever inputs 'list item 1' into the Textbox (the object in the Middle Pane) - the Right Pane's label will automatically change the color of the line/list item called 'list item 1'. This then allows me to glance over to the Right Pane at any time and see which list items are present in the text. Likewise, if 'list item 1' is deleted from the Textbox, the text 'list item 1' in the Right Pane's label will revert to its default color.

I've spent a long time researching solutions that I can learn from and the only thing I can think of is to have 50 separate labels in the right Pane stacked on top of each other - each corresponding to a different line of text in the txt/srt file. So, for example 'list item 1' would have its own label and so on. Then I could do a separate if statement for each of the 50 labels - but I'm aware this would slow the program, especially since it's constantly searching through what could be up to a 50,000 word text box.

Unfortunately I don't know of any other solution and I'm now facing the problem of not being able to search the scrollable Textbox - I understand this error is related to integers but I don't see how that relates to what I'm asking.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if lines[7] in Entry:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1489, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

**I would like to search the scrollable Textbox for whatever is present at Line 13 in the List's txt/rtf file**. How a TRUE result changes the label's Textbox color is another issue, I'll look into once I can return a statement.

Here is the code that I believe is relevant:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import WORD

root = Tk()


m1 = PanedWindow(bg='#3E4753')
m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
m2 = PanedWindow(m1, orient=VERTICAL, bg='#3E4753')
m1.add(m2)
m1.add(m2, stretch="always")
m3 = PanedWindow(m1, orient=VERTICAL)
m1.add(m3)
m1.add(m3, stretch="always")
m4 = PanedWindow(m1, orient=VERTICAL, background="grey")
m1.add(m4)
m1.add(m4, stretch="always")





#CLASSES
class WrappingL(tk.Label):
    '''a type of Label that automatically adjusts the wrap to the size'''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.update_wrap)

    def update_wrap(self, event):
        self.config(wraplength=self.winfo_width())

# OPEN FUNCTIONS
    with open('script.rtf','r+') as f:
        script=''.join(f.readlines())

    with open("script.rtf","r") as fi:
        headings = []
        for ln in fi:
            if ln.startswith("#"):
                headings.append(ln[1:])

    f=open('reminders.rtf', 'r')
    lines=f.readlines()



    #BODY
    Entry = ScrolledText(m3)
    Entry.pack()
    Entry.insert(END,script)


    #HEADINGS
    labelHeadings = ScrolledText(m2, bg='#3E4753', fg='#FFFFFF', font="none 14 bold")
    labelHeadings.pack()
    labelHeadings.insert(END,headings)


    #LINES
    #Each line
    labelRem_line1_text = lines[13]
    labelRem_line1_text.pack(ipadx="25")

    #searching
    ##Line 1
    if lines[13] in Entry:
        print("yeah") #need to figure out code if TRUE to change labelRem_line1's text color
    else:
        print("no matches") #change this to do nothing later
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to achieve, but for the error you mentioned you can just cast the `int` into string by `str(your_int)`

Comment: That was my confusion, I don't have an int - I have an Entry Textbox which consists of text and a rtf file which also consists of text. As for the whole purpose, I'm just trying to get create a text viewer - the left pane displays the text's headings and the right pane (which is where the problem is) displays a (checklist) list from an rtf file. I'm not sure how to turn this into one with selectable checkmarks so I've opted for a color-changing mechanism for each item of the list.

Comment: @hunterlang: *" I don't have an int"*: You are using the reference object `Entry`. Change to `if lines[13] in Entry.get('1.0', 'end'):` Read [Tkinter.Text.get-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.get-method)

Comment: thank you for the response (same for Henry), I looked over the link and implemented the suggestion but I still receive the same error https://imgur.com/a/AwWffbt - there must be something I'm misunderstanding (I thought the error was telling me that either Entry or the lines value was an integer)

Comment: @hunterlang Please update your question with the error as text.